# Assign quantities to a standard lot size

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have standard lot sizes of 20, 22 and 24 pallets and i need to merge fractional orders to meet the lot sizes automatically.

Please help with a vba solution.

Before and after illustrations pasted below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO (StackOverflow)! Well, SO is not a code writing service, this type of question with no attempt and no tries are usually not well received and tend to attract downvotes. Please, before post a question, research, try something and only then post your question with the summary of you have tried so far and a specific problem that you're facing. Also, check our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want it to minus the formatting

```
Public Sub PackingExample()
    Dim Data As Variant, Pack As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, PackTotal20 As Long, PackTotal22 As Long, PackTotal24 As Long, NextOrder As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Data = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 3)).Value2
        ReDim Pack(1 To UBound(Data, 1))

        For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
            NextOrder = i
            PackTotal20 = 0: PackTotal22 = 0: PackTotal24 = 0
            Do
                PackTotal20 = PackTotal20 + Data(NextOrder, 3)
                PackTotal22 = PackTotal22 + Data(NextOrder, 3)
                PackTotal24 = PackTotal24 + Data(NextOrder, 3)
                NextOrder = NextOrder + 1
                If NextOrder > UBound(Data, 1) Then Exit Do
            Loop Until PackTotal24 + Data(NextOrder, 3) >= 24

            i = NextOrder - 1

            If PackTotal20 <= 20 Then
                Pack(i) = 20
            ElseIf PackTotal22 <= 22 Then
                Pack(i) = 22
            ElseIf PackTotal24 <= 24 Then
                Pack(i) = 24
            End If
        Next i

        With .Cells(1, 4)
            Range(.Offset(1, 0), .Offset(UBound(Pack), 0)).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Pack)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```